# Stuck GCC version is preventing me from installing packages

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, dependencies, 20.04

I'm running a fairly fresh (not release upgraded) install of Kubuntu 20.04. I'm in a "fully updated" state, as in apt update + apt full-upgrade tell me I am up to date.

I would like to install:

```
sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd
```

But:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mesa-opencl-icd : Depends: libclc-r600 (>= 0.2.0+git20180312-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libclc-amdgcn (>= 0.2.0+git20180312-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is originally caused by:

```
sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd libclc-r600 libclc-amdgcn libclang-common-9-dev lib32gcc-s1 lib32stdc++6 gcc-10-base lib32gcc1 
gcc-10-base is already the newest version (10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32gcc-s1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
 lib32gcc1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
 lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Synaptic shows me that there is a newer version and my current one is obsolete:
[image]
[image]

I can't remove it, because I have packages that depend on it that are in return depended upon by basically all of my packages:

```
sudo apt remove gcc-10-base libgcc-s1 libstdc++6 libc6 zlib1g util-linux openjdk-11-jre-headless libxtst6 libxrender1 libxi6 libxext6 libx11-6 libpcsclite1 libnss3 liblcms2-2 libjpeg8 libfreetype6 libfontconfig1 libcups2 libasound2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'openjdk-11-jre-headless' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alsa-topology-conf alsa-ucm-conf amd64-microcode apport-symptoms binutils-common breeze-cursor-theme cgroupfs-mount colord-data
  cups-common cups-server-common debconf-kde-data distro-info-data dns-root-data emacsen-common filezilla-common
  ... ALL THE PACKAGES BASICALLY ...
  libsmartcols1 (due to fdisk) findutils grep libpcre3 (due to grep) install-info (due to grep) gzip hostname init
  systemd-sysv (due to init) init-system-helpers (due to init) perl-base (due to init-system-helpers) libc-bin login
  libaudit1 (due to login) libpam0g (due to login) libpam-runtime (due to login) libpam-modules (due to login) mount
  util-linux (due to mount) ncurses-bin sed sysvinit-utils libcap-ng0 (due to util-linux) libudev1 (due to util-linux)
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1738 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5.705 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

These are my active apt repos:

```
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/serge-rider/dbeaver-ce/ubuntu eoan main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiagohillebrandt/postman/ubuntu focal main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-git/ubuntu focal main
deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
deb http://deb.xanmod.org releases main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rpardini/adoptopenjdk/ubuntu focal main
```

I tried force replacing the version in synaptic, but as expected, that will still make it remove basically all the packages. I also attempted manually installing the current version from the deb file, but that also breaks consistency. So my question is, how can I replace gcc-10-base and the other "obsolete" packages, without having to reinstall everything, so that I can continue installing the package I want?

UPDATE 1:
I used

```
aptitude search ?obsolete
```

to find and remove two unrelated truly obsolete packages. gcc-10-base was not among them, so it's not obsolete I guess, but it also isn't the newest version, and also there are no updates available for it. Where is it coming from, since the entire OS is dependent on it?

UPDATE 2:
I removed all third party debs to make sure there were no weird conflicts. It didn't help.

UPDATE 3:
Reinstall isn't possible because it isn't on any repo anymore.

```
root@anvil:/etc/apt# sudo dpkg -l | grep gcc-10-base
ii  gcc-10-base:amd64                             10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04                        amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
root@anvil:/etc/apt# sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-10-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of gcc-10-base is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I have since reinstalled my OS, reusing my partitions. My data and most applications remained available (switched from Kubuntu to pop os) - still I'm curious how it was possible to deviate from the repositories this much and if there's a way to fix it?